# Log click event on html link using Amplitude SDK

Tags: javascript, amplitude-analytics

I'm trying to log an event when a `<a>` link is clicked before navigating to the final destination, this is what I have so far:

```html
<a href="/account" data-event-type="select_account">My account</a>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-event-type]').forEach(link => 
  link.addEventListener('click', function onLoggableActionClicked(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    amplitude.getInstance().logEvent(link.getAttribute('data-event-type'));
                  
    window.location.href = link.href;
  })
)
```

The event fires perfectly but the event doesn't get logged, maybe because the request is ended when the browser is redirected?

I tried using a callback but waiting for it makes the navigation impossible:

```js
function onLoggableActionClicked(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  amplitude.getInstance().logEvent(link.getAttribute('data-event-type'), null, function() { window.location.href = link.href });
})
```

How can I log events for outbound links?

Comment: It's possible the event is being batched on the next page view. If you send a `logEvent` for pageviews, check the payload on that later request as I've noticed Amplitude will batch previously triggered but incomplete events in the events array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beacon` transport method which uses `window.navigator.sendBeacon()` under the hood which is designed to send asynchronous requests, ensuring their continuation even if the user navigates away:

```
amplitude.init('AMPLITUDE_ID', {
  transport: 'beacon',
  flushIntervalMillis: 0,
  flushQueueSize: 1,
});
```

https://www.docs.developers.amplitude.com/data/sdks/typescript-browser/#use-sendbeacon